# Native app (hybrid) to use django-social-auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, nativeapplication

I already have implemented social authentication using facebook and google in my web application (Django + used django-social-auth). I want my native app built with (Kendo UI + Icenium) to re-use the Oauth from my web application.

What is the best way to do this? I've used django-tastypie in my web app, but not sure how i can integrate rest API with Oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Python social auth can be used to for social oauth with rest

1. Retrieve oauth token(access token) using client side flow using for web [hello.js](https://adodson.com/hello.js/) or satellizer or any native module(simpleauth etc)
2. Use a ajax request to send access_token to django for signing in or registering new user. https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token